# Не срабатывает onclick

Tags: javascript

```
 <select id="type" >
        <option onClick="TypeSearch('addr');" selected> по адресу</option>
        <option onClick="TypeSearch('map');">по карте</option>
 </select>
```

А вот функция:

```
function TypeSearch(tS)
    {
        alert ("Есть контакт");
        if (tS=="map")
            {
             alert ("Карта");
            jQuery("#searchA").css("display","none");
            jQuery("#searchM").css("display","inline-block");
            };
        if (tS=="addr")
            {
            alert ("адрес");
            jQuery("#searchM").css("display","none");
            jQuery("#searchA").css("display","inline-block");
            };
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильней будет примерно так:

```
<select id="type" onchange="TypeSearch(this.value)">
     <option value="addr" selected> по адресу</option>
     <option value="map">по карте</option>
</select>
```

Comment: спасибо, работает